# Fastest way to get average time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a data set with name and datetime as columns
There are multiple entries of name with different datetimes

eg. input:

```
 name    datetime
 ------------------
  A1  2018-07-20 17:04:20.486
  A1  2018-07-18 17:48:30.910
  A1  2018-07-18 19:13:05.636
  A1  2018-07-17 15:01:30.976
  A1  2018-07-17 18:21:13.113
  B7  2018-07-18 16:38:33.410
  B7  2018-07-18 17:30:46.893
  B7  2018-07-17 15:45:48.673
  B7  2018-07-18 03:01:41.826
  B7  2018-07-19 18:12:40.923
  C3  2018-07-18 19:07:41.973
  C3  2018-07-17 16:59:51.646
  C3  2018-07-18 19:41:41.280
  C3  2018-07-20 16:01:44.543
  C3  2018-07-20 16:01:22.860
```

I need to just figure out the mean/avg TIME for each name

sample output:

```
name    avg_time
 B7    14:13:54
 A1    17:29:44
 C3    17:34:28
```

Solution #1

I have tried to replace the date with current date and then perform 
groupby on name and get the mean time

```
today = pd.datetime.today()
data['datetime'] = data['datetime'] .apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=today.day, month=today.month, year=today.year))

for name, group in data.groupby(by='name'):
    avg_datetime(group['datetime'])

# avg_time calculation
def avg_datetime(series):
    """
    takes a series of datetime and returns the avarage time in '%H:%M' format
    :param series:
    :return:
    """
    series = pd.to_datetime(series)
    dt_min = series.min()
    deltas = [x - dt_min for x in series]
    avg_datetime = dt_min + functools.reduce(operator.add, deltas) / len(deltas)
    return avg_datetime.time().strftime('%H:%M')
```

Solution #2

I have also tried to convert the time to total number of minutes and then 
calculate the mean and change back the format

```
# convert to total minutes
dt_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(data['datetime']).dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
data['total_mins'] = dt_index.hour * 60 + dt_index.minute

mean_mins_list = [[name, int(group['total_mins'].mean())]
                  for name, group in data.groupby(by='name', sort=False, as_index=False)]
avg_time_df = pd.DataFrame(mean_mins_list, columns=['name', 'avg_time'])

# revert to HH:MM format
avg_time_df['avg_time'] = avg_time_df['avg_time'].apply(lambda x: str(math.floor(x / 60)) + ':' + str(x % 60))
```

my dataset is very huge, ~ 10 million unique names, what is the fastest way to perform this operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option.

Calculate the total number of seconds for each `datetime` from the start of that day. Then groupby and calculate the mean, since they are just numbers at that point. Finally, convert back to a `datetime`, and just select the time part.

```
import pandas as pd

df['secs'] = (df.datetime - df.datetime.dt.normalize()).dt.total_seconds()
pd.to_datetime(df.groupby('name').secs.mean(), unit='s').dt.time
```

Output:

```
name
A1    17:29:44.224200
B7    14:13:54.345000
C3    17:34:28.460400
Name: secs, dtype: object
```